# GET value from web table

Tags: vba, vb6, vba6

based this code i need to get also the link value from each row in table.

Actually i get only PR and PROVINCIA

reference link: https://www.comuniecitta.it/sigle-province-italiane

for example of first row i need:

AG
AGRIGENTO
https://www.comuniecitta.it/sicilia-19/provincia-di-agrigento-84

code:

```
Sub AGG_PROVINCE(ByVal MYURL As String)

    Dim oDom As Object, PR As String, PROVINCIA As String
    Set oDom = CreateObject("htmlFile")
    Dim X As Long, Y As Long
    Dim oRow As Object, oCell As Object
    Dim DATA() As String

    Y = 1
    X = 1

    With CreateObject("msxml2.xmlhttp")

        .Open "GET", MYURL, False
        .Send
        oDom.body.innerHtml = .responseText

        'Debug.Print .body.innerHtml

    End With

    With oDom.getElementsByTagName("table")(0)

        ReDim DATA(1 To .Rows.Length, 1 To .Rows(1).Cells.Length)

        For Each oRow In .Rows

            For Each oCell In oRow.Cells

                DATA(X, Y) = oCell.innerText

                Y = Y + 1

            Next oCell

            Y = 1
            X = X + 1

        Next oRow

    End With

    Dim intFile As Integer
    Dim strFile As String
    strFile = "C:\Lavori_Vb6\LEGGI_CSV_COMUNI\CSV\PROVINCE.csv"
    intFile = FreeFile
    Open strFile For Output As #intFile

    Dim K As Long
    For K = 1 To UBound(DATA)

        PR = UCase(DATA(K, 1))
        PROVINCIA = UCase(DATA(K, 2))
        
        Print #intFile, PR & ";" & PROVINCIA

    Next K

    Close #intFile

End Sub
```

other way are welcome? naturtally

Comment: VBA or VB6? Or VB.Net? And why do you tag this as vb6-migration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the link itself from `oCell.getElementsByTagName("a")(0).getAttribute("href")` but obviously the link is only present in the cells in the 2nd column so you need to do something like this ... replace

```
DATA(X, Y) = oCell.innerText
```

... with ...

```
If oCell.getElementsByTagName("a").Length > 0 Then
    DATA(x, Y) = oCell.innerText & ", link: " & oCell.getElementsByTagName("a")(0).getAttribute("href")
Else
    DATA(x, Y) = oCell.innerText
End If
```

... which will append the link to the inner text (you might want to add it as a seperate item in your DATA array, or however you want to handle it?)

> UPDATED CODE FOR COMMENT

Add this at the start of your Sub

```
Dim HLINK As String
```

Change your ReDim to

```
ReDim DATA(1 To .Rows.Length, 1 To .Rows(1).Cells.Length + 1)
```

Then replace the If with

```
DATA(x, Y) = oCell.innerText
If oCell.getElementsByTagName("a").Length > 0 Then
    DATA(x, Y + 1) = oCell.getElementsByTagName("a")(0).getAttribute("href")
Else
    DATA(x, Y) = oCell.innerText
End If
```

In the final For/Next, add

```
HLINK = UCase(DATA(K, 3))
```

And change the Print to

```
Debug.Print PR & ";" & PROVINCIA & ";" & HLINK
```

Comment: i need a seperate item in myDATA array, plesse, Tks in other case for code.

Comment: i jOHN YOUR CODE WORK PERFECT NOW!!!! Tks for patince. Pizza from Italy, Napoli!

Comment: Glad to have helped (and the virtual pizza!). If you are happy with the answer then please click on the check/ tick to mark it answered, this keeps the focus on other unanswered questions.